# How can I debug the contents of variables after they're sent by an AJAX post() request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm new to async requests and I'm trying to submit a form's contents into the database.  The data is received and validated, and the callback function shows that the request was sent successfully, but nothing is put into the database.  When I hard-code the values to go into the database the mysqli query is submitted successfully, so I think the issue is the php file receiving the $_POST data.

Normally I would just disable any redirection and echo the contents of the variables in my .php file or alert(var) to see what is being received (or not received) from the form, but with the asynchronous request I can't do either.

My next idea was writing them into a file to check their values, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Heres the jQuery function(s):

```
var formObj = $(this);
var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "addCal.php",
    data:  formData,
    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
 alert("Entry added!");
 $('input#food').val('');
 $('input#fullness').val('');
 $('input#datepicker').val('');
 $('textarea#notes').val('');
},
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
 {
  alert("unsuccessful!");
 }          
});
```

and here's the contents of addCal.php:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

$food = $_POST["food"];
$fullness = $_POST["fullness"];
$day = $_POST["day"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
$year = $_POST["year"];
$notes = $_POST["notes"];
$username = $_COOKIE["user"];

$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)

// submit data
  mysqli_query($result, "INSERT INTO `food` (`food`, `fullness`, `user`, `notes`, `date`)
  VALUES ('$food', '$fullness', '$username', '$notes', '$date')")
     or die(mysqli_error($result));

?>
```

Comment: have you tried console.log(formData); ?

Comment: if that comes back empty or null then your values are not getting into your formData.

Comment: Check the returned data in success callback - `console.log(data);` anything output by php will be in there

Comment: Yup you defently need to have a proper debugger for the server side (i feel like remembering Xdebug was something) as well as at least a request interceptor on your client side (like firebug for firefox or similar). Unfortunately thats best i can provide currently - hence this is just a comment.

Comment: Eclipse + XDebug. I followed this tutorial that I found very useful

Comment: This works perfectly and is much less hamfisted than how I used to do it.  I'd like to accept your reply as the answer if you'll post it, Steve.